How to append multi-line text with spaces to end of file if that text does not exist in bash?
I'm trying to append a text string that contains newlines and spaces to a file if the whole string doesn't already exist in that file.
Ideally done in a way that's portable across MacOS and Linux
I was able to get it working with a single line of text, however multi-line text does not work.
I have tried this:
RC=(
  "# MyProg PATH Variables"
  "export PATH=\"\${HOME}/.local/myprog/bin\""
)

# Concat string and convert " " into "\ "
COMMAND=""
for LINE in "${RC[@]}"; do
  LINE_ESCAPED=$(echo "$LINE" | sed "s/ /\\ /g")
  COMMAND="$COMMAND$LINE_ESCAPED\n"
done

printf "$COMMAND" # Prints correctly

EXISTS=$(grep -F "$COMMAND" foo.txt)
if ! [ "$EXISTS" = "" ]; then
  echo "skipping"
  exit
fi

printf "$COMMAND" >> foo.txt

However grep fails.

POSIX grep treats each line of the pattern argument as a separate pattern, so I doubt what you want can be done portably using grep. That said, what is that loop doing? Why are you escaping spaces? Spaces aren't special in grep.

I had to escape the spaces because apparently grep takes a filename as a second argument - grep string filename. Without escaping the string it would fail thinking there was a second argument.

Not if you have quoted your variables, which you apparently have.

Please update the question with RC actually containing an item with a newline, for example "# MyProg"$'\n'"# PATH Variables" instead of the first item.

I think the string OP wants to check is $"# MyProg PATH Variables\nexport PATH=\"\${HOME}/.local/myprog/bin\"' (joining the entries in RC with a newline). That's what they're trying to build in COMMAND, except they use \n instead of a newline (and then are probably misled by the output of printf "$COMMAND").

You really don't want to use CAPS for shell variable names. Since, by convention, global environment variables are capitalized, it is bad practice to also use caps for your own, local variables because this can lead to naming collisions and hard to find bugs.

This answer uses the fact that set(1p) without parameters outputs variables in the form suitable for (re)input to the shell:

The value string shall be written with appropriate quoting; see the description of shell quoting in Quoting. The output shall be suitable for reinput to the shell, setting or resetting, as far as possible, the variables that are currently set; read-only variables cannot be reset.

It then uses grep to compare the quoted forms of the "patterns" with the quoted form of the contents of the file.
The only downsides are:

The variable contents, if the script is sourced instead of executed, will stay in the environment and any previous value of that variable will be destroyed.
The whole contents of the file is read into a variable. For sufficiently large text files, this might not work. In that case, creating a specialized program in some programming language might be a better solution.
It passes $s to printf(1p) directly, on purpose, to interpret the contents of s as a formatting string. This is generally not recommended, but necessary in this case.

#!/usr/bin/env bash
output="$1"
add_strings=('Hello, world!' 'Some text\nanother line')

if [ -z "$output" ]; then
    printf "%s needs an argument\n" "$0" >&2
    exit 1
fi

touch "$output"
for s in "${add_strings[@]}"; do
    contents=$(cat "$output")
    grep -qF "$s" <(set | grep ^contents=) ||
        printf "$s\n" >> "$output"
done

example usage:
When the file testfile does not exist and script is run repeatedly:
$ bash add.bash testfile
$ cat testfile
Hello, world!
Some text
another line
$ bash add.bash testfile
$ cat testfile
Hello, world!
Some text
another line

When one multiline "pattern" exists in the file:
$ cat <<! >testfile
Some text
another line
!
$ cat testfile
Some text
another line
$ bash add.bash testfile
$ cat testfile
Some text
another line
Hello, world!

When one line of a multiline "pattern" exists in the file:
$ cat <<! >testfile
Some text
!
$ cat testfile
Some text
$ bash add.bash testfile
$ cat testfile
Some text
Hello, world!
Some text
another line


I'm not sure, if grep is POSIX, but no need of external command
RC=( "# MyProg PATH Variables"
     "export PATH=\"\${HOME}/.local/myprog/bin\"")
IFS=$'\n'; COMMAND=${RC[*]}
text_data=$(<foo.txt)
[[ $text_data =~ "$COMMAND" ]];
[[ ${#BASH_REMATCH[*]} == 0 ]] && printf "%s" "$COMMAND" >> foo.txt


https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/grep.html

Sorry, this doesn't work if the items in RC contain newlines. For example, RC=("Some text"$'\n'"another line") and if foo.txt contains Some text as first line and another line as another, this script will add another copy of those two lines.

@Vilinkameni ok, i thought RC is containing the new lines. Each line as an item and the whole string should be match I'm trying to append a text string that contains newlines and spaces to a file if the whole string doesn't already exist in that file.. So each line must be searched in the script, not the whole string?

The question assumes searching a text file for items which are multiline "strings", and adding those items if they are not found in the file. The current form of the answer doesn't fulfill that request. I admit that the current example from the question is not illustrative enough of this, which I suggested in a comment to the question.
